# How to show all the elements that are in hidden using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Toggle</title>
<style>
        table, td, th {
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        height:50px; 
                  }
    td {width:200px;
    }
    body {
        padding: 50px;
    }
</style>
<script>
    var ind;
    $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#table tr").click(function () {
                if ($(this).index() > 0)
                $(this).hide();
            });
            $("#table th").click(function () {
                var ind = $(this).index();
                $("td:nth-child("+(ind+1)+")").toggle();
            });

    });
    function change() {

            $("tr").show();
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="display" onclick="change">Show all</button>
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Company
        </th>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Color
        </th>
        <th>
            type
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Audi</td>
        <td>Q6</td>
        <td>Metalic grey</td>
        <td>SUV</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jaguar</td>
        <td>A8</td>
        <td>Black</td>
        <td>Sedan</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ambassador</td>
        <td>Classic</td>
        <td>White</td>
        <td>Sedan</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Mahindra</td>
        <td>Scorpio</td>
        <td>White</td>
        <td>SUV</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

When i click the tr it will hide.I need to show all the hidden tr when i click the button.And i also written code for hiding a column.But when i hide 3rd column contents of 4th column occupying the 3rd column making the 4th one empty.Can anyone direct me correctly.Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `<button id="display" onclick="change()">Show all</button>`

Comment: @ Milind But it is not working.

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/p7d22Lgy/2/

Comment: Change is a function you should use as change() not change

Comment: why are you using jQuery for some events, and inline script for others. Pick one or the other

Comment: Thanks it works fine.Can i have answer for second question which i have asked above?

Comment: need to hide corresponding `th` also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button id="display" onclick="change()">Show all</button>
```

You forgot the `()`.

Comment: Thank you it worked.I also written code for hiding a column.But when i hide 3rd column contents of 4th column occupying the 3rd column making the 4th one empty.can anyone correct me?

Comment: When you're using `hide()`, the `display` is set to `none` and in your case, the 4th column "takes over" the 3rd. To prevent that, use `.css("visibility", "hidden")` instead of `.hide()`.

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function () {

```
        $("#table tr").click(function () {
            if ($(this).index() > 0)
            $(this).hide();
        });
        $("#table th").click(function () {
            var ind = $(this).index();
            $(this).toggle();
            $("td:nth-child("+(ind+1)+")").toggle();
        });

});
```

Please add the code $(tihs).toggle() as shown in above.As you only write  code to hide the tds not th. If you want to show that columns again in your button click please add this to your change function.

$("th").show();
$("td").show();